# modX Revo - вывод MIGx внутри pdoPage

Tags: modx

Вывожу список товаров (ресурсов) с помощью pdoPage.

У каждого ресурса имеются ТВ-поля: помимо обычных, есть еще мультиполе `MIGX` (можно добавлять множество строк для таблицы параметров).

```
[[!pdoPage?
  &tpl=`@INLINE
    <div class="catalog__item">
       <a href="/[[+uri]]">[[+tv.product_name]]</a>
       <table>

          [[getImageList?
            &docid=`15`
            &tvname=`product_params`
            &tpl=`@CODE:
            <tr><td>[[+param-name]]</td><td>[[+param-value]]</td></tr>
          `]]  

        </table>
        <div class="catalog__price">[[+tv.product_price]]</div>
    </div>`
    &sortby=`{"createdon":"ASC"}`           
    &includeTVs=`product_price,product_name`
    &parents=`4`
    &pageLimit=`20`
   ]]
```

Не знаю, позволено ли вообще размещать `getImageList` внутри `pdoPage`...

Но общем-то работает всё, кроме одного:

`&docid='15'` - означает, что выведены значения MIGX-поля ресурса с `ID=15` - т.е. у всех товаров одни и те же значение, взятые у ресурса 15.

Если же указать `&docid=[[+id]]` - не сработает (видимо берется ИД текущей страницы - той, где выведен наш список ресурсов-товаров.

__

Прошу подсказать, как вывести каждому ресурсу в списке ресурсов свои собственные значения `MIGx` ТВ поля?

Answer (score 1):

Помощи не дождался, дождался просветления.

в getImageList указываем всё же:
    &docid=`[[+id]]`

а в pdoPage в качестве шаблона, вместо inline указываем, например:
    &tpl=`catalog-item`

Создаем чанк catalog-item, а в нём getImageList.

По итогу getImageList будет в отдельном месте и всё работает...